# DbExpress use in delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-2007, dbexpress

I am new in delphi 2007. I need to connect with SQL Server and update , insert and delete DB values from my local database(SQLServer) through DBExpress. Anyone can help step to step guide from scratch if anyone has usefull tutorial. kindly send the link. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link for you. [A Guide to Using dbExpress in Delphi database applications](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/a/dbexpressguide.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In past our company had many issues with dbExpress. So, I will not recommend dbExpress for the serious database application development. 2 years ago we started to look around for an alternative and purchased [Anydac](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/). Works great with SQL Server and other DB's. Actually, there are few others 3d party libraries. So, consider to try them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for blowing my own trumpet, but I've written a few [blog entries](http://nbnewman.blogspot.com/search/label/dbexpress) about converting BDE based applications to dbExpress. True, my target was Firebird and not SQLServer, but that shouldn't matter too much.

I too use Delphi 7.